# A subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$ is a direct summand iff $G/H$ is free?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum, free-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H\le G$. Then TFAE:

- $G/H$ is free.
- $H$ is a direct summand of $G$.

This is how I tried to prove this theorem:

If $G/H$ is free, then $G/H$ has a basis.  Let's denote this basis as $(g_1H, g_2H, ..., g_nH)$, where each $g_i$ is an element of $G$.
We need to find a subgroup $K$ such that : $G=H\oplus K$. Let $K=\langle g_1,g_2\dots,g_n\rangle $
First, we need to show that $H\cap K=\{0\}$.

Let $h\in H\cap K$, then $h\in H$ and $h=\sum k_ig_i$ where $k_i\in \mathbb{Z}$.
$h\in H\Rightarrow \bar{h}=hH=H$, which implies that $h$ is congruent to the identity element modulo $H$.
Then

$$\begin{align}
\bar{h}=\bar{\sum k_ig_i}=\bar{0} &\Rightarrow k_1g_1H+\dots +k_ng_nH=0\\
&\Rightarrow k_1=k_2=\dots =k_n=0\\
&\Rightarrow h=0,
\end{align}$$

then $H\cap K=\{0\}$.

Next we need to show that every element $x$ of $G$ can be written as $x=h+k$ where $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

Let $x\in G$, then $\bar{x}=x+H\in G/H\Rightarrow x+H=k_1(g_1+H)+\dots +k_n(g_n+H)$ where $k_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x+H=(k_1g_1+\dots k_ng_n)+H\Rightarrow (k_1g_1+\dots k_ng_n)-x\in H$

$\exists h\in H$ such that $k_1g_1+\dots k_ng_n-x=h\Rightarrow x=(-h)+(k_1g_1+\dots +k_ng_n)\in H+K$

Seconde implication :

$H$ is a direct summand of $G$, there existe $K\leq G$ such that $G=H\oplus K$.
Let $xH\in G/H$, where $x\in G$, then $\exists !h\in H$ and $k\in K$ such that $x=h+k$.

$xH=x+H=(h+k)+H=k+(h+H)k+H\Rightarrow \bar{x}=\bar{k}$.

Let {$k_iH$}$_i$ be all the distincts cosets generated by $K$, then $G/H=<k_iH>$.

Next we need to show that this set is linear independence.

If $\sum_i d_i(k_i+H)=\bar{0}=H$ where $d_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $$\sum_i d_i(k_i+H)=\sum_i(d_ik_i)+H=H \Rightarrow \sum_i d_ik_i\in H\Rightarrow \sum_i d_ik_i=0$$

But how can I show that $d_i=0,\forall i$

Comment: Not following.  Say $H$ is the trivial group.  That's a direct summand of $G=<e>\oplus \,G$.  Does that mean that $G$ is free?

Comment: What do you mean by "free" in this context?  A free group, or a free abelian group, are well defined terms...but maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Since you expand "$G/H$ is free" with "$G/H$ has a basis", you should make explicit that you are talking of $\Bbb Z$-modules (i.e. abelian groups).

Comment: Solution for $\implies$: $x+H\subset\sum(\Bbb Zg_i+H)=K+H.$ (But $\impliedby$ is false indeed.)

Comment: Expanding lulu's first comment, if $H$ is any abelian group and $Q$ is any nonfree abelian group, $H$ is a direct summand of $G=H\oplus Q$ but $G/H\cong Q$ is not free. But your proof is correct in showing the other implication: if $G/H$ is free, then $H$ is a direct summand.

Comment: How can I show the second implication? I tried to construct a basis for G/H, but I could not.

Comment: You can't. Please read the comments.